# Multithreading - how to get all threads ticking at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok so I have a thread Customer that runs through some code. But I want it to sleep after completing a particular method (setShopTime, and setCheckoutTime) that decreases a counter to zero. At each decreasing tick in the counter, I want the customers to stop, until every other thread has also had their tick reduced by 1. Baring in mind though, not all customers, will be ticking on the same method as there are two. Would the best way to do this to sleep each thread after running the method, have another thread that acts as a tick counter, that then interupts the other threads after each tick to get them moving again? I just worry about this because if one customer is still running and the tick counter thread interupt goes off it might screw things up a bit?

I'll show you the runnable and perhaps some more wiser people than myself can give me some tips on how best to approach this? I've put in comments where I would want each sleep.

```
class customerRunnable implements Runnable {

private Customer customer;
private CheckoutFloor checkoutFloor;
private Lock customerLock;
private Condition customerReady;

public customerRunnable(CheckoutFloor checkoutFloor) {
    customer = new Customer();
    this.checkoutFloor = checkoutFloor;
}

public void run() {
        customer.addRandomShopTime();
        while (customer.shopTime > 0) {
            customer.setShopTime();
            //sleep
        }
        CheckoutOperator checkoutOperator = checkoutFloor.weightedCheckoutDeterminator();
        checkoutOperator.addCustomer(customer);

        while (customer.checkoutTime > 0) {
            if (checkoutOperator.customerList.get(0) == customer) {
                customer.setCheckoutTime();
                //sleep
            }
        }
        checkoutOperator.removeCurrentCustomer();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I think there are folks who would like to help but I have to tell you, your question leaves too much to guesswork.  Try and restate your requirements.  On the surface, I'm thinking wait/notifyAll() if you want all waiting threads to wake up at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a modified version of this would fit your needs:

```
public class Example
{
    int counter1 = 10;
    int counter2 = 10;

    public class Thread1 extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            try
            {
                while (Example.this.counter2 > 0)
                {
                    // Do your stuff

                    synchronized (Example.this)
                    {
                        Example.this.counter1--;
                        Example.this.notifyAll();
                        Example.this.wait ();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public class Thread2 extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            try
            {
                while (Example.this.counter1 > 0)
                {
                    // Do your stuff

                    synchronized (Example.this)
                    {
                        Example.this.counter2--;
                        Example.this.notifyAll();
                        Example.this.wait ();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use sleep to modify the behavior of threads. The JVM decides when a thread gets to run and you will find yourself simply adding longer and longer sleep times until the threads are running sequentially instead of concurrently. Even if it seems to work once in a while, it won't be deterministic.

In your code you are consuming CPU time with your while loop when you should be blocking on an external event. Look at using a semaphore that decrements your tick counter and is shared between the threads.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to use a Barrier. Here is the documentation of a CyclicBarrier with some examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html